# In excel 2013 how to use IF ELSE CONDITION?

Tags: excel, formula

I want to evaluate some forms and in that I have used this formula.

[image]

But in some fields I received this blank result. For that I want to keep 0 value but just now its taking -2.

Any help to set 0 for blank, -2 for No and 4 for Yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this nested if statement:

```
=IF(F20 = "Yes",4,IF(F20 = "No",-2,0))
```

It first tests for "Yes" if that is false then it test if it is "No" if that is false it returns 0.

Comment: @KingsAdam please consider marking as correct.  It is something only you can do.  click on the green check mark by the answer.

Comment: Carner i know that but stack over doesn't allow me to accept it within 10 minutes

Comment: @KingsAdam ah, I did not realize we were up against the time limit.  Too many people do not understand that until it is clicked the question remains open.  And that just upsets my OCD. :)